# Can I pray outloud

Tags: salat

***Prayer: Out loud or not?***

Hello. I usually like to pray the prayers of asar, duhr and fajr outloud. Is that fine?

Comment: Why do you do that?

Comment: Not a scientific but a practical answer: It doesn't really matter as long as you don't disturb others.

Comment: Of course it isn't because these prayers ('asr and dhohr) are supposed to be performed as silent prayers. You will at least need to perform sujd Sahw for repairing this mistake. But if you did so intentionally knowing this it's a bit more of an issue.

Comment: Oh. To be honest I did know that you had to pray them silent. Ok, from now on I will pray them silent.

Comment: Also, with nafil prayers, can they be prayed outloud?

Comment: That is a different question which should be asked separately and it would need a focus because many specific nafl/sunnah prayers are supposed to be done loud ('e.g. I'd, taraweeh) while the daily ones are rather silent. Note a comment is not an answer (at least not a final answerl, comments are rather intended for clarification.